# Return files from specified directory where Filesize is less than 40kb

Tags: php, filesize, glob

i want to select file form directory where filezise in less then 100kb. please check my code its not working

```
<?php
ob_start();
$dir = '/home/couponsc/public_html/testfile';
$ext = '.mp3';
$search = $_GET['s'];
$results = glob("$dir/*$search*$ext");

    foreach($results as $item) 
    {
        $sizes= filesize($item);
        if($sizes < 100);
        {               
            echo $item;             
        }

    }   



?>
```

Comment: `filesize()` returns bytes, not KB, you'll want to put `$sizes < 100*1024`.

Comment: after adding this its show all files which are less or more then 100kb

Comment: So it shows all files?  Is `filesize($item)` returning `false`?  You might need to prepend `$dir` to `$item` in `filesize($dir . '/' . $item)`.

Comment: i want to delete all file where file size is equal to 44kb

Comment: Right, well that's simple enough if the basic loop and file size enquiry is working, which is what you are trying to achieve in that code.  Is it working?

Comment: foreach($results as $item) 
  {
   $sizes= filesize($item);
   if($sizes < 40*1024)
   {    
    unlink($item);   
   }
    
  }

Comment: can you please send me code to how can delete file which are 44kb in folder.

Comment: That would delete all files under 40KB, if `filesize($item)` is working.

Comment: Does it show the correct files with the `echo`? The test for 44KB, depends if you want exactly 44KB `($sizes == 44*1024)`, something that is between 44KB and 45KB `($sizes >= 44*1024 && $sizes < 45*1024)` or anything that rounds to 44KB `($sizes >= 43.5*1024 && $sizes < 44.5*1024)`.

Answer (score 1):

`if($sizes < 100);`
You have a semi-colon after your if-clause -> empty statement.

```
foreach($results as $item) {
    $sizes= filesize($item);
    if($sizes < 40*1024) {
        echo $item, "\n";
    }
}
```

Or with a bit more [spl](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)/[lambda](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) fun + recursion:

```
<?php
$path = 'c:/temp';
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

$it = new FooFilterIterator($it, function($e) { return $e->getSize(); }, function($e) { return $e < 40*1024; } );

foreach($it as $f) {
    printf("% 6d %s\n", $f->getSize(), $f);
}

class FooFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
    protected $getter;
    protected $filter;

    public function __construct(Iterator $source, $getter, $filter) {
        parent::__construct($source);
        $this->getter = $getter;
        $this->filter = $filter;
    }

    public function accept() {
        $f = $this->filter;
        $g = $this->getter;
        return $f( $g($this->current()) );
    }
}
```

there's also the [GlobIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php).

Comment: Great answer, beat me to it!! Was going to suggest `RDI` as well.

Comment: Yeah, but that's only the fun section - would need much more explaination to be helpful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `filesize()` function returns bytes, and not kilobytes, thus your condition doesn't work.

the correct condition is:

```
if($sizes < 102400);
```